# mmap offset when using a struct

Tags: c, struct, shared-memory, mmap, lseek

I've got this struct:

```
typedef struct ip_row {
  sem_t row_lock;
  char row_name[NAME_SIZE];
  char row_address4[NAME_SIZE]; // IPv4 address name
  char row_address6[NAME_SIZE]; // IPv6 address name
} ip_row_t;
```

I would like to use the struct multiple times in a shared memory file.I have verified that for exactly one use, it works.

```
int shmfd; //Shared memory file descriptor
struct ip_row *data;

/*...creating shared memory and map...*/
shmfd = shm_open(shared_memory, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP );
ftruncate(shmfd,FILESIZE);
data = (ip_row_t*)mmap(0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shmfd,0);

/*...getting to user inputs, this stuff is in a loop...*/
strcpy(data->row_name,ipstr1);       
strcpy(data->row_address6,ipstr2);  
strcpy(data->row_address4,ipstr3);
```

When I run the loop again, the writing starts at the beginning of the shared memory file, overwriting what was there before. How can I move the offset so I can support more entries into the shared memory? I've tried these two:

```
lseek(shmfd,sizeof(struct ip_row_t),SEEK_CUR); //segfault when we write agian
data = (ip_row_t*)mmap(0, FILESIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shmfd,sizeof(struct ip_row_t)); //also segfaults when we try to read
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
`

Comment: "When I run the loop again." You haven't shown a loop. What you *say* is a loop copies the same (undeclared) data into the same strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use pointer arithmetic on `struct ip_row *data;` to reach "further" in your mmaped shared memory since mmap returns nothing but a pointer to a memory region of `FILESIZE`, which happens to be mirrored into shared memory.
For example use `data[0]` to access first copy, `data[1]` to access second etc.
`lseek` on shared memory object is unspecified and your second `mmap` causes segfault because you are trying to `mmap` `FILESIZE` bytes to a `FILESIZE` memory region that has been allocated to you but at an `sizeof(struct ip_row_t)` offset, thus effectively going outside the memory you are allowed to access, besides, offset has to be multiple of `getpagesize()`, which in this case it probably is not.